# Mostrar e ocultar vídeos ao passar o mouse sobre uma texto

Tags: html

O efeito seria semelhante ao "Tooltip" como mostrado abaixo, mas mostraria um vídeo já com *autoplay* enquanto o mouse estivesse sobre a palavra, ao deslocar o mouse fora da palavra o vídeo seria ocultado/finalizado.

Não será necessário estilos como mostrado no exemplo, o vídeo precisa ser mostrado em algum local ao redor do texto em que o mouse estiver sobre.

Serão vários vídeos em palavras diferentes, as mesmas palavras citadas ao longo do texto mostrarão o mesmo vídeo correspondente, exemplo: A palavra substantivo será mostrada várias vezes, e todas elas terão o mesmo vídeo.

Como se a explicação de algumas palavras em um texto HTML, exibissem um vídeo quando o mouse estiver sobre ela.

Exemplo do Tooltip (Acredito que não será este comando talvez o onmouseover)

```css
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -5px;
  right: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Left Tooltip w/ Right Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

tente isto:

HTML:

```
<p>text</p>
<video src="myfile.mp4"/>
```

JS:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
p[* /*este é o numero do <P> sendo 0 o primeiro p,e 9 o décimo*/].onmouseover = function() {
    var video = getElementsByTagName("video");
    video[*].style.overflow = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Era isso o que você queria?

Comment: Cara pegando o elemento por ID se ele tiver 10x a mesma palavra ele vai ter que ter 10 IDs diferente! E replicar esse seu JS 10x, o ideal seria fazer por classe e não por ID

Comment: Pera aí, vou reformar o código...

Comment: Pronto, mais ou menos assim?

Comment: EduApps, a implementação foi boa e está funcionando. Mas estou com um problema:
1) Como são muitos vídeos a página carrega todos antes de começarem a funcionar, como carregar sobe demanda, ou seja, carregar somente aqueles em que o mouse é posicionado sobre as palavras?
2) Tem uma solução para que o vídeo fique dentro da página, pois se o texto que contém o vídeo estiver muito a esquerda, ao posicionar o mouse a página ganha uma barra de rolagem horizontal para comportar o vídeo.
Obrigado!